# Error xception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to Clases.Doctor

Tags: java-swing

Tengo que sacar los datos de un array y mostrarlo en una tabla, estos datos cambian segun el doctor que elija en un jcombox. Entonces mi idea es la siguiente un meotod mostrar en tabla y llamo a ese metodo en elItemStateChanged de ese jcomobox. No se si me exlico. Desde que he creado el metodo y lo llamo me da el error al intentar ejecutar el proyecto.
Este es mi metodo

```
 public void mostrarTabla() {
        Doctor d = (Doctor) cmbDoctor.getSelectedItem();
        for (int i = 0; i < d.getListaCitas().size(); i++) {
            Cita c = d.getListaCitas().get(i);
            int idC = c.getNumerocita();
            Paciente pac = c.getPac();
            Date fecha = c.getHora();
            modelo.addRow(new Object[]{idC, pac, fecha});
            tablaCitas.setModel(modelo);
        }
    }
```

El problema este en el casting pero no entiendo porque puesto que el objeto que me da el casting es un Doctor.
Este es el metodo para cargar el cmbDoctor para que veais que carga doctores

```
public void cargaListaMedicos() {
        int i;
        int seleccionado = cmbEspecialidad.getSelectedIndex();
        String puestoCombo3;
        String especialidad = "";
        cmbDoctor.removeAllItems();
        listaDocFiltrados = new ArrayList<>();
        switch (seleccionado) {
            case 0:
                especialidad = "";
                break;
            case 1:
                especialidad = "Cirugía";
                break;
            case 2:
                especialidad = "Medicina general";
                break;
            case 3:
                especialidad = "Pediatría";
                break;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < listaDoctores.size(); i++) {
            Doctor d = listaDoctores.get(i);
            if (especialidad.compareToIgnoreCase(d.getEspecialidad()) == 0) {
                listaDocFiltrados.add(d);
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < listaDocFiltrados.size(); i++) {
            puestoCombo3 = listaDocFiltrados.get(i).getNombreDoctor();

            cmbDoctor.addItem(puestoCombo3);
        }
    }
```

No se si necesitáis algo mas. Gracias porque sin vosotros no saco el proyecto adelante mi profesor pide mas de lo que enseña.

Comment: Aquí `Doctor d = (Doctor) cmbDoctor.getSelectedItem();` intentas asignar una cadena (String) a un objeto de la clase `Doctor`  lo cual no es posible. Si lo que recoges ahí es el nombre del doctor digamos, debes pasarlo al constructor de la clase, por ejemplo: `Doctor d = new Doctor ( cmbDoctor.getSelectedItem() );` Si no funciona así, dinos que es lo que intentas hacer en esa línea realmente.

Comment: Gracias me he dado cuenta del error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El mensaje de error:

> ```
>  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>  Clases.Doctor
> ```

Indica que un objeto de la clase `String` no puede ser convertido a un objeto de la clase `Doctor`.

Eso ocurre porque en esta línea quieres precisamente asignar un `String` como un objeto `Doctor`, lo cual es imposible:

```
Doctor d = (Doctor) cmbDoctor.getSelectedItem();
```

Suponiendo que lo que obtienes al llamar a `cmbDoctor.getSelectedItem()` es el nombre del doctor u otra propiedad de la clase, debes pasarla en el constructor de la clase:

```
Doctor d = new Doctor(cmbDoctor.getSelectedItem());
```

De ese modo, se creará una nueva instancia de la clase `Doctor` con el parámetro que le hayas pasado.